# How to use {{Yield}} helper with hash helper in ember js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

Can somebody explain with an example about yield helper with hash which is used while using with components in emberjs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Link](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.7/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/hash?anchor=component) to using hash helper with yield in ember components.

Yield is used to **[share data within your component with the content it is wrapping](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/wrapping-content-in-a-component/#toc_sharing-component-data-with-its-wrapped-content)** and It's used only in block form of components.

Hash helper is used to create [object](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.7/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/hash?anchor=hash). The hash helper is a generic builder of objects, given hash arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Implement `yield` in your `template.hbs`:

```
{{yield (hash
  foo=(component "path/to/component/foo")
  bar=(component "path/to/component/bar")
)}}
```

And you can instance it like this:

```
{{#baz
  as |x|
}}
  {{x.foo}}
  {{x.bar}}
{{/baz}}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: how do you pass data with the foo component above?

Comment: @Craicerjack I usually do:

```
{{ x.foo data=somedataref }}
```

Comment: Sorry I meant in the hash foo component but its cool, figured it out

Answer (score 1):

Using `{{yield}}` is discussed in [Ember Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/wrapping-content-in-a-component/) including a small example. You can find another, more detailed example in [tutorial application](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/autocomplete-component/) that is part of Ember Guides.

Comment: an example here in the answer is better than linking to one :)

Comment: Totally, but in my opinion this is not a valid question at all and Ember Guides will stay up to date.